# Update only specific fields

Tags: django

```
//views
def newEnroll(request):

    GradeYear = request.POST.get['customers']
    payment = request.POST.get['paymentID']
    pending = "Enrolled"
    update = StudentUser.objects.filter(PaymentTypes=payment,pending=pending,Grade_Year=GradeYear)

    update.Grade_Year = ([GradeYear])
    update.PaymentTypes = ([payment])
    update.Request = ([pending])
    return render(request, 'accounts/pending.html')

//model
class StudentUser(models.Model):
      Grade_Year = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
      Subjects = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
      SectionID = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
CourseID = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
PaymentTypes = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   RoomID = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
   Request = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request,blank=True)
```

I'm getting this error

'method' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused between filter() and get(). When you use filter(), it returns to you an iterable queryset, which you can use to update accordingly. On the other hand, get() returns you the required object, which can be accessed through the variable you have created.

If you use filter(), you typically do this whenever you expect more than just one object that matches your criteria. If no item was found matching your criteria, filter() returns am empty queryset without throwing an error.

If you use get(), you expect one (and only one) item that matches your criteria. Get throws an error if the item does not exist or if multiple items exist that match your criteria. You should therefore always use if in a try.. except .. block or with a shortcut function like get_object_or_404 in order to handle the exceptions properly.

Examples

```
q = SomeModel.objects.filter(name="Donald Trump")

print (q) -> [QuerySet1, QuerySet2, QuerySet3]
```

```
q = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1)
print (q) -> [QuerySet object ... pk=1]
```

Note: What you get from get() is not iterable and what you get from filter() is iterable and will have to iterate to get the desired object.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
update = StudentUser.objects.filter(PaymentTypes=payment,pending=pending,Grade_Year=GradeYear)
```

to

```
update = StudentUser.objects.filter(PaymentTypes=payment,pending=pending,Grade_Year=GradeYear)[0]
```

filter returns a list,u need to add [0] in last of filter to get the first object from the list

Comment: thak you but it doesnt work.

Comment: what is the result  of request.POST.get['customers'] ?

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Yeah, you need to add update.save() in last

Comment: and why are you writing update.Grade_Year = ([GradeYear]) , you can't save a list in fields of an object

Comment: gradeYear = request.POST['customers']
    payment = request.POST['paymentID']
    pending = "Enrolled"

    update = StudentUser(
        Grade_Year=gradeYear,
        PaymentTypes=payment,
        Request=pending
    )
    
    update.Grade = gradeYear
    update.PaymentTypes = payment
    update.Request = pending
    update.save()

Comment: please help me to correct my code

Answer (score 0):

```
//views
def newEnroll(request):

    GradeYear = request.POST.get['customers']
    payment = request.POST.get['paymentID']
    pending = "Enrolled"
    update = StudentUser.objects.filter(PaymentTypes=payment,pending=pending,Grade_Year=GradeYear)[0]

    update.Grade_Year = GradeYear
    update.PaymentTypes = payment
    update.Request = pending
    update.save()
    return render(request, 'accounts/pending.html')
```

Try this

Comment: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: ohh got it,my bad . You need to use () instead of []

Comment: request.POST.get('customers') and request.POST.get('paymentID')

Comment: its okay, btw I encounter another error , "list index out of range"

Comment: Great, the code is working fine, StudentUser.objects.filter() is returning an empty list, and i have putted [0] in last of query, that's why the error is "list index out of range"

Comment: If there is any StudentUser with PaymentTypes=payment,pending=pending,Grade_Year=GradeYear this credentials then it will not give this error.You can use try except in order to handle the exception

Comment: no update happen in my database and the error keep showing this "list index out of range" i dont know how to fix this, please help me.

Comment: First create a StudentUser in database with a gradeyear,pending,payment and take the same gradeyear,pending,payment in request.POST.get and then use StudentUser.objects.filter(), it will not give error this time

Comment: StudentUser.objects.filter() will return a list,it will return an empty list if there is no Studentuser with same credentials as gradeyear,pending and payment

Comment: class StudentUser(models.Model): 
   . 
   .
   .
   Grade_Year = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   CourseID = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   PaymentTypes = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
   Request = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
       suser ='{0.Firstname}---{0.Middle_Initial}---{0.Lastname}---{0.Request}'
       return suser.format(self)

Comment: let me explain,StudentUser.objects.filter(PaymentTypes=payment,pending=pending,Grade_Year=GradeYear) this will give a valid result only if you have a Studentuser object with credentials of same payment,pending and Grade_year as passed in the filter

Comment: I have already a model for StudentUser but i want to update some of field (Grade_Year, PaymentTypes and Request)

Answer (score 0):

```
//views
def newEnroll(request):

    GradeYear = request.POST.get['customers'] //let GradeYear is 3
    payment = request.POST.get['paymentID'] // payment is 100
    pending = "Enrolled"
    update = StudentUser.objects.filter(PaymentTypes=payment,pending=pending,Grade_Year=GradeYear)[0]
    //StudentUser.objects.filter(PaymentTypes=100,pending="Enrolled",Grade_Year=3)[0] will not give error if there is a StudentUser object in model with PaymentTypes=100,pending="Enrolled",Grade_Year=3
    update.Grade_Year = GradeYear
    update.PaymentTypes = payment
    update.Request = pending
    update.save()
    return render(request, 'accounts/pending.html')
```

Comment: Your method is wrong,first you are filtering StudentUser with some Credentials then you are updating same credentials in the StudentUser

Comment: u can do StudentUser.objects.get(id=1) instead of tudentUser.objects.filter()[0], this will call first oobject of StudentUser and update it, try this. id will be the id of StudentUser Object

Comment: I get it now, Thank you very much :)

Comment: you welcome :) .